# use @import in css with angularjs causes a CORS exception

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to import a font for the css file, but I see that angularjs throws an exception that (from what I've read) points to a CORS restriction.

This is a simple @import font command, and I don't need/not using angularjs features in the css file.

Then, how to avoid that?

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300italic,700italic,300,700";
```

The exception

```
[Exception... "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object" code: "15" nsresult: "0x8053000f (InvalidAccessError)" location: "<unknown>"]
```

Cheers

UPDATED: solved by manually downloading the fonts and pointing the css direction to the local url (using the css sheet retrieved by going to the google direction).
But still, it seems that angularjs should not interfere with css CORS petitions I'd say (?)

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Added in the question, and as I also say there I've solved this by avoiding the CORS petition, which I guess is the best solution, but raises the question of why angularjs interferes with css petitions (maybe it is trivial, I just don't know)

Comment: That error is not from angular